# when i include php code nothing is displayed in browser

Tags: php, html

learning php and i was building simple login form by php but after i run the code the white screen come in the browser and even the html part was not displayed in the browser.

```
    <?php 
    function redirect($location )
    {
header("Location: " . $location);
    }
    exit;?>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if ($username == "s9iper1" && $password == "secret") {
 redirect("https://www.facebook.com/bil30als?ref=tn_tnmn");
} else{
$username = $_POST["username"];

$message  = "loggin {$username}";
    }
    }
else{
$username = "";
$message = "there were some errors.";
    }

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>second page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $message;?>
<form action="form_single.php" method="post" >
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username);
?>"/><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: how are you running this file? have you setup any local server ?

Comment: enable error reporting in your script, using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: did you forget the php opening tag ? `<?php`

Comment: Well, you have an `exit;` there before anything gets printed, so of course the script stops. Perhaps you meant for it to be inside the function?

Comment: i have edit my code please see it again.

Comment: @ManinGreen yes i have setup local server xampp

Comment: Try removing "exit;" on line 6.

Comment: display error and display startup error both are at ON status

Comment: @quasivivo  when i am entering my details and pressing submit it says: Undefined variable: username in /opt/lampp/htdocs/form_single.php on line 5 AND LINE  5 IS   if ($username == "s9iper1" && $password == "secret")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your whole code because it just had too many errors ;)

```
<?php 
    function redirect($location )
    {
        header("Location: " . $location);
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $username = (string) $_POST["username"];
        $password = (string) $_POST['password'];

        if ($username == "s9iper1" && $password == "secret") {
            redirect("https://www.facebook.com/bil30als?ref=tn_tnmn");
        } else{
            $username = (string) $_POST["username"];

            $message  = "loggin {$username}";
        }
    }

    if (empty($message)) $message = '';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>second page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <form method="post" >
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username);?>"/><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i am entering my details and pressing submit it says: Undefined variable: username in /opt/lampp/htdocs/form_single.php on line 5 AND LINE 5 IS if ($username == "s9iper1" && $password == "secret")

Comment: Change $username to `$_POST['username']` and $password to `$_POST['password']`

Answer (score 0):

Is it whole code?
If yes you are missing start tag

Comment: `<?php`, sorry I missed the code tag in my answer

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the reason it does not work, is that you are requesting validation from different file. 
If the code you posted is in index.php, the form needs to ask validation from index.php as well.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" >
```